# How can I improve this PCB schema for L293D H-brigde?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, pcb-design, h-bridge

I am building a machine that requires a lot of steppers, I've used breadboards until now, and now I plan on getting the driver based on a PCB. I have used Fritzing to design the PCB, and since it's my first design I'm just wondering if it's correctly made.

L293D schema:

[image]

My PCB design:

[image]

Will this work? The motor supply, do I really need an own connection for it, or can I just send it to 5V and to ground? Are things at an all right distance from each other? Is there anything I've missed? This is my first design I'm actually planning on producing, so hoping to get some feedback on it.

Based on comments, I've implemented some changes. I keep the first image for reference. 
**Second revision:**

[image]

I have put the Fritzing PCB sketch up on [github](https://github.com/haaakon/Electronics).

Comment: Surely you will want some bypass and supply filter capacitors.  Does the data sheet give any recommendations?

Comment: Except the decoupling caps I would add a remark: You have non 45° traces, replace by 45°. This looks more profesional

Comment: I would certainly connect the four ground pins on the IC together under the IC.  I would also bring all external connection points to the edge of the board, and group related connections - the two connection points for the L motor should be adjacent, as should be those for the R motor.  I would probably arrange and size the external connection points so that I could install screw terminal strips if desired (even if I didn't plan to install terminal strips  initially).  As others have said, I would add bypass capacitors on all supplies, and make sure I met all data sheet recommendations.

Comment: @PeterBennett How is it possible to do the grouping without the copper lanse crossing each other? Like grouping the gnd to one pin below the IC is hard since they are in the middle. Do you have a tip on how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing is the lack of bulk  capacitance for the H-bridge (the V2 connection) that is tight to GND. LOW inductance, lots of copper.

You need to bulk up on the copper for the GND plane going through the middle of the chip

The 4 traces going to the machine terminals need to be bulked up.

Your silkscreen placement is non-intuitive to the terminal meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by the 4 traces to machine terminals need to be bulked? Does this apply to the second revision as well?

Comment: Yes it does. When I say "bulk" I mean thicken up the 4 terminals to the machine. This chip can give just over 1Amps, its just good practice to ensure they are a reasonable thickness - Check against IPC. You need to increase the copper around Pins: 4,5,12,13  Like just have solid copper under the chip and around it. These are for heatsinking and referencing